# Find the minimum and maximum values in the nested object

Tags: javascript, reduce

I have a deeply nested javascript object with an unlimited amout of children. Every child has a value.

```
var object = {
     value: 1,
     children: {
      value: 10,
      children:{
       value: 2,
       children: {...}
      } 
     }
}
```

All attempts to make a recursive function did not succeed, it turned out to go down only to a lower level.

Comment: What was your previous unsuccessful attempt?

Comment: Reopening.  The linked question is quite different: no recursion is needed in that one..

Answer (score 3):

After flattening your linked list into an array, you can use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) with an accumulator that is a tuple of `min` and `max`, starting with initial values of `Infinity` and `-Infinity` respectively to match the implementations of [`Math.min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) and [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max):

```js
const object = {
  value: 1,
  children: {
    value: 10,
    children: {
      value: 2,
      children: {
        value: 5,
        children: null
      }
    }
  }
}

const flat = o => o == null || o.value == null ? [] : [o.value, ...flat(o.children)]
const [min, max] = flat(object).reduce(
  ([min, max], value) => [Math.min(min, value), Math.max(max, value)],
  [Infinity, -Infinity]
)

console.log(min, max)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `children` is an object with only one value (vs an array with potentially many), this is a pretty simple recursive function. The base case is when there are no children in which case both min and max are just the value. Otherwise recurse on the children to find the min and max:

```js
var object = {
  value: -10,
  children: {
   value: 4,
   children:{
    value: 200,
    children: {
      value: -100,
      children: null
    }
   } 
  }
}

function getMinMax(obj) {
  if (!obj.children || obj.children.value == undefined)
     return {min: obj.value, max: obj.value}
  else {
    let m = getMinMax(obj.children)
    return {min: Math.min(obj.value, m.min), max: Math.max(obj.value, m.max)} 
  }
}

console.log(getMinMax(object))
```

Answer (score 1):

Short and simple, for min change `Math.max` to `Math.min`

```js
var test = {
   value: 1,
   children: {
    value: 10,
    children:{
      value: 2,
      children: {}
    }
   }
}
function findMaxValue(obj) {
  if (Object.keys(obj.children).length === 0) {
    return obj.value;
  }
  return Math.max(obj.value, findMaxValue(obj.children))
}
console.log(findMaxValue(test))
```