# Find min value and max value key nested object

Tags: javascript, reduce

I have an object with multiple nesting. Each of the objects has its own keys, iq, name, total. It is necessary to find, for example, the maximum and minimum value of the iq. The key child may or may not be.

```
let infoList= {
    name: Jone,
    iq: 130,
    children: [{
        name: Joy,
        iq: 121,
        children: [{
            name: Ross,
            iq: 110,
            children: [{
                ....
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: How is this different than your last: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53379069/find-the-minimum-and-maximum-values-in-the-nested-object

Comment: key children is an array of objects, because the decision to get the result did not work.Can you help rewrite that code as an array of objects?

Comment: This looks like a json object.So in which patfor you need like javascript,jquery and angular or others

Answer (score 2):

Here's a recursive solution. Note that I changed the names to strings.

```
let infoList= {
    name: 'Jone',
    iq: 130,
    children: [{
        name: 'Joy',
        iq: 121,
        children: [{
            name: 'Ross',
            iq: 110,
            children: [{ name: 'Joe', iq: 20 }]
        }]
    }]
}

function ancestorIQs(person) {
  let arr = [person.iq];
  if (!person.children) return arr;
  return person.children.reduce(function (iqs, child) {
    return iqs.concat(ancestorIQs(child));
  }, arr);
}

let result = ancestorIQs(infoList);

console.log(Math.min(...result)); // 20
console.log(Math.max(...result)); // 130
```