# Find minimal and maximum values in a tree like object using recursion js

Tags: javascript, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree

I'm trying to find min and max values in tree like object using recursion, but I don't actualy understand how to find this values. Also my function must be pure and I can't use loops or forEach. Only map, reduce, filter are avalaible. So this is how my data looks like:

```
const tree = {
children: [ 
    { 
        children: [
            { 
                children: [],
                values: [15.667786122807836]
            }
        ],
        values: [35.77483035532576, 1.056418140526505]
    },
    {
        children: [
            {
                children: [
                    {
                        children: [],
                        values: [67.83058067285563]
                    }
                ],
                values: [98.89823527559626]
            }
        ],
        values: [51.49890385802418, 41.85766285823911]
    },
],
values: [6.852857017193847, 28.110428400306265, 51.385186145220494]};
```

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
const min = graph => {
if (!graph.children.length && !graph.values.length) return;

if (!graph.children.length && graph.values.length) {
    return Math.min(...graph.values);
}

return graph.children.map(el => {
    const minValue = Math.min(...el.values);
    min(el);
    return minValue;
});
```

};

But this not work well. So guys can anybody explain how the callstack works, maybe give me some good examples, and explain how to solve my problem. Thanks for the help and sorry for the bad English). Oh, and also)) how to get the distance between two nodes in the different depth level?

Comment: you realize that map, reduce and filter are all loops too right? see: [Find the minimum and maximum values in the nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53379069/find-the-minimum-and-maximum-values-in-the-nested-object)

Comment: Thanks for the help, good post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually with homework questions, I would prompt for more dialog with the OP, but as this already has a working, accepted answer, I'll just add a simpler one:

```js
const min = ({values = [], children = []}) => 
  Math .min (...values, ... children .map (min))

const tree = {children: [{children: [{children: [], values: [15.667786122807836]}], values: [35.77483035532576, 1.056418140526505]}, {children: [{children: [{children: [], values: [67.83058067285563]}], values: [98.89823527559626]}], values: [51.49890385802418, 41.85766285823911]}, ], values: [6.852857017193847, 28.110428400306265, 51.385186145220494]};

console .log (min (tree))
```

We just use `Math.min`, spreading the current values and the results of recursive calls to each of its children into arguments to it.  We default both `values` and `children` to empty arrays in case either is missing at any node.

Clearly `max` is a trivial change to this.

Comment: It looks so simple), thank you Scott,, finally because of your and Johnny Mopp's help I finally start understand how the recursive calls works and when they will return values

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a JS programmer but am always looking to practice. Here's what I came up with:

```js
const tree = {
  children: [{
      children: [{
        children: [],
        values: [15.667786122807836]
      }],
      values: [35.77483035532576, 1.056418140526505]
    },
    {
      children: [{
        children: [{
          children: [],
          values: [67.83058067285563]
        }],
        values: [98.89823527559626]
      }],
      values: [51.49890385802418, 41.85766285823911]
    },
  ],
  values: [6.852857017193847, 28.110428400306265, 51.385186145220494]
};

function treeMin(graph) {
  if (graph.children.length == 0) return Math.min(...graph.values);
  return Math.min(...graph.values,
                  graph.children.reduce((prev, cur) =>
                     Math.min(prev, treeMin(cur)), Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
                  ));
}

console.log(treeMin(tree));
```

I gave the function a name to make the recursive calls. The first thing it does is check if there are no children. If not, it just returns the min of the values.

If there are children, return the min of values and the result of calling `reduce` on the children. Inside `reduce`, the recursive calls are made.

Note: it does not handle the case where `values` is empty. This can be easily added.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I tried many different combinations but your example it's all what I need. By the way don't you know how can I take distance between two points for example min and max?